# Amazon ec2 website launch

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webserver

I have used apache tomcat server for my project on my personal system to develop a website. However I need to deploy the website on amazon ec2 instance. I need a stable alternative for apace tomcat. Please suggest me some options and links. Also while deploying my personal website what kind of security measures must I take to ensure that integrity of my data is not compromised.

Comment: Check this little tutorial out: https://sites.google.com/site/amistrongeryet/setting-up-java-tomcat-on-ec2

Answer (score 1):

**EC2 Setup**

1. Launch an EC2 instance using Amazon's ami-84db39ed (fedora-8-i386-v1.14-std) AMI.  This appears to be a basic Fedora 8 image.
2. ssh into the instance, using a command like:

   ```
   ssh -i <path to your .pem file> root@<public DNS address for your instance>
   ```

All subsequent command lines are executed in the instance, except where noted.

**Install Java**

Download a JDK RPM from http://download.java.net/jdk6/.  Look for "Linux RPM in self-extracting JDK file" under "Linux Platform".  I downloaded jdk-6u20-ea-bin-b02-linux-i586-01_apr_2010-rpm.bin, by copying the link address and then running curl:

```
curl http://www.java.net/download/jdk6/6u20/promoted/b02/binaries/jdk-6u20-ea-bin-b02-linux-i586-01_apr_2010-rpm.bin
```

**Install Tomcat**

I installed it under /env/tomcat, for no reason other than the fact that the Amazon EMI used by Amazon's Eclipse plugin does so.

```
mkdir /env
mkdir /env/tomcat
cd /env/tomcat
curl http://apache.mirrors.hoobly.com/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.26/bin/apache-tomcat- 6.0.26.tar.gz > apache-tomcat-6.0.26.tar.gz
tar zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.26.tar.gz
cd apache-tomcat-6.0.26
bin/startup.sh  # this launches Tomcat
```

To verify the installation, load the root page from a web browser:              http://mypublicdns.com:8080

(Substitute the public DNS address of your instance, as shown on the EC2 dashboard.)

**Configure Tomcat to launch automatically**

Create a file "/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat" with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Tomcat init script for Linux.
#
# chkconfig: 2345 96 14
# description: The Apache Tomcat servlet/JSP container.

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_20
CATALINA_HOME=/env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.26
export JAVA_HOME CATALINA_HOME

exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh $*
```

You may need to tweak JAVA_HOME and/or CATALINA_HOME, depending on exactly which versions of the Java SDK and Tomcat you installed.  Next, execute these commands to set the proper permissions for your init script and enable Tomcat for auto-launch:

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat
chkconfig --level 2345 tomcat on
```

Tomcat should now be automatically launched whenever your server restarts.

**Install your application**

Now, we'll install our web application and tweak the Tomcat configuration a bit.  First, edit the server.xml file using "vi conf/server.xml".  Look for the connector for port 8080:

```
   <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

and change the port from 8080 to 80, so that your web server is accessible on the normal HTTP port.  Next, find the Host tag (near the end of the file):

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
```

Change autoDeploy to "false".  (This is recommended by O'Reilly's Tomcat: The Definitive Guide, 2nd Edition.  I didn't quite follow their reasoning, it had something to do with applications being installed twice at server startup, once by autoDeploy and once by a different mechanism.)  Finally, inside the  tag, add a  tag for your application.  Mine looks like this:

```
  <Context docBase="CloudMetricsEC2.war" path="" />
```

Now you can close server.xml.  Next you need to build a WAR file for your application -- in Eclipse, you can do this by right-clicking on the project in Package Explorer, choosing "Expore...", and choose "Web -> WAR file" from the list of export formats.  Copy it to the instance using a command like this (on your local machine, not the EC2 instance):

```
 scp -i ~/.ec2/Tomcat2.pem CloudMetricsEC2.war
 root@INSTANCE_PUBLIC_DNS_NAME:/env/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps/CloudMetricsEC2.war
```

Next, remove the default ROOT application, or at least move it out of the way:

```
 mv webapps/ROOT webapps/xROOT
```

Finally, restart Tomcat to pick up all the changes:

```
 bin/shutdown.sh; bin/startup.sh
```